# Which is the recommended way to use the Null Pattern in Python?

Tags: python, design-patterns, mocking

The other day I was coding when suddenly I discovered myself struggling with a simple problem but confuse solution (at least in a pythonic way to go).

The code was supposed to just download some files, for that, it would call some `DownloadController` passing it a `callback` so to received events such as `init`, `progress`, `error` and `success`.

**However, my code didn't need at all these events**. With this came to my mind some solutions

- Change `DownloadController` to have a default `callback=None` and check for it so to ignore sending events in this case
- Have `NullCallbackImpl` which adheres to callback interface but do nothing (just `pass` on each event)

First approach didn't like it because the code would be kind of messy and not well-design.

So, I stick with the second approach... Questions:

- How good (maybe 'how bad') would it be to have a `null_callback = mock.Mock()`? (using python mock library from Michael Foord)

  - Is there any library that do this?
- Or should I stick with creating a `NullCallbackImpl` implementing each method with a simple `pass`?

Comment: Mocks record every call. You don't want every event to generate a bunch of garbage logs.

Comment: That's a good point. Indeed, the only argument I need to just avoid doing this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You discovered a new use case for DownloadController - "Let the user customize the callback". It sounds like you have control over the Downloadcontroller source. It could define a DownloadCallback class that exposes the events as methods but does nothing with them. The Controller would accept None (do nothing) or anything that implements the DownloadController interface.

I think using mock for real code is more than a bit odd... it creates yet another dependency that needs to be met for users of your module.

Comment: The first sentence seems quite correct in this case. The "user" might be able to handle the call back as she want (show progress with UI, etc.)
I would stick for now with the proposed solution, however, I would like to find some way to just put a "null_object" that handles everything for me... in every case... which ever the interface is...